# Get date about Posts on LinkedIn

Tags: social-media, serviceexecute

I'm doing some experiments on my LinkedIn Page. Each week I post a image on LinkedIn. Then I follow the number of views during the day's after. Each time a change something. For example, the time of the post. Or, the kind of content (humor, nice, neutral).  I want to know the impact of each change on the number of views and likes/reshares after the post. For your information, the next graph is based on 4 post in the last month.[image]

It's a little bit boring to go each hour to my Linkedin Page to write down the number of views. I have some experience with webscraping.  So I tried:

```
Import["https://www.linkedin.com/in/myname/detail/recent-\
activity/ca/share-analytics/urn:li:activity:----------/"]
```

The server returned the HTTP status code 999

I Also tried:
linkedin = ServiceConnect["LinkedIn", "New"]

This works, LinkedIn generate a number. But after it, each request failed.

What I want:

- each hour select the number of views/likes and reshare (of my own
  post)
- each hour select the Business Owner viewed your post
- Append
  the resulat in a a file, including a timestamp
- export the file each
  day